# catchError operator showing problem in angular interceptor

Tags: angular, angular-http-interceptors

I am developing an interceptor for handling http error in angular 10 project. Here is the code:

```
import { HttpEvent, HttpHandler, HttpInterceptor, HttpRequest, HttpResponse } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, of } from 'rxjs';
import { catchError, map } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class HttpErrorHandlerServiceService implements HttpInterceptor {

  constructor() { }

  intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
    return next.handle(req)
    .pipe(
      map(resp => { 

       }),
      catchError(err => { 

       })
    );
      
  }
}
```

In catchError operator the below error is showing.

> Argument of type '(err: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter
> of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<void | HttpSentEvent |
> HttpHeaderResponse | HttpProgressEvent | HttpResponse |
> HttpUserEvent>) => ObservableInput<...>'.
> Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput'.
>
> ```
> 19       catchError(err => {
> ```

Answer (score 1):

RxJS [`catchError`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/operators/catchError) operator *must* return an observable. If you have nothing to return you could forward the supplied error using RxJS [`throwError`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/throwError) function.

```js
import { throwError } from 'rxjs';

return next.handle(req).pipe(
  map(resp => { }),
  catchError(err => { 
    // handle error
    return throwError(err);      // forward the supplied error
  })
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can gracefully handle the error by return an `Observable` message like :

```js
import { of } from 'rxjs';

catchError(err => of('Error happened'))
```

or forward it like :

```js
catchError(err => throwError(err))
```

In either way you have to return an `Observable`. You have good exemples [here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/catch)